# My loop isn't running

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a code in Python to get all the 'a' tags in a URL using Beautiful soup, then I use the link at position 3 and follow that link, I will repeat this process about 18 times. I included the code below, which has the process repeated 4 times. When I run this code I get the same 4 links in the results. I should get 4 different links. I think there is something wrong in my loop, specifically in the line that says y=url. I need help figuring out what the problem is.

```
import re
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
list1=list()
url = 'https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html'

for i in range (4):  # repeat 4 times
    htm2= urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup1=BeautifulSoup(htm2)
    tags1= soup1('a')
    for tag1 in tags1:
        x2 = tag1.get('href', None)
        list1.append(x2)
    y= list1[2]
    if len(x2) < 3:  # no 3rd link
        break  # exit the loop
    else:
        url=y             
    print y
```

Comment: `if len(x2) < 3` should be `if len(list1) < 3`, and `y= list1[2]` should be in the else portion of that if conditional. I doubt that's the reason you're getting five of the same link, but it's a potential issue nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're continuing to add the third link EVER FOUND to your result list. Instead you should be adding the third link OF THAT ITERATION (which is `soup('a')[2]`), then reassigning your url and going again.

```
url = 'https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html'
result = []

for i in range(4):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    links = soup('a')
    for link in links:
        result.append(link)
    try:
        third_link = links[2]['href']
    except IndexError:  # less than three links
        break
    else:
        url = third_link
        print(url)
```

This is actually pretty simple in a recursive function:

```
def get_links(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    links = soup('a')
    if len(links) < 3:
        # base case
        return links
    else:
        # recurse on third link
        return links + get_links(links[2]['href'])
```

You can even modify that to make sure you don't recurse too deep

```
def get_links(url, times=None):
    '''Returns all <a> tags from `url` and every 3rd link, up to `times` deep

    get_links("protocol://hostname.tld", times=2) -> list
    if times is None, recurse until there are fewer than 3 links to be found
    '''

    def _get_links(url, TTL):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
        links = soup('a')
        if (times is not None and TTL >= times) or \
           len(links) < 3:
            # base case
            return links
        else:
            return links + _get_links(links[2]['href'], TTL+1)
    return _get_links(url, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code
`y= list1[2]`
just prints the URL located at index 2 of `list1`. Since that list only gets appended to, `list[2]` doesn't change. You should instead be selecting different indices each time you print if you want different URLs. I'm not sure what it is specifically that you're trying to print, but `y= list1[-1]` for instance would end up printing the last URL added to the list on that iteration (different each time).

Comment: I tried all the solutions above, none of them worked for me so far. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @Julia_arch I think I misunderstood your attempt originally. My current answer should solve your problem (grabbing ALL links, then following the third link and grabbing ALL links there, too.)